# Método que regresa variables genéricas

Tags: java, variables, metodología

soy nuevo en la comunidad y también en la programación. En una de mis clases empezamos a ver las listas simplemente enlazadas y las estamos construyendo desde 0 en java. Al principio definimos la clase lista con variables genéricas para no tener que hacer una lista para cada distinto tipo de dato. Mi duda viene en uno de los métodos, quiero hacer un método que me regrese un dato en el índice i, pero no sé como manejar los casos en los que el método no encuentra el índice indicado

```
public T obtener(int i)
{
    if(this.primerNodo == null)
    {
        return ;
    }
}
```

Como ven intento manejar el caso en el que la lista esté vacía, pero no sé que regresar en este caso, no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre el manejo de estas variables genéricas.
Cualquier ayuda es recibida :D

Comment: Te dejo mas información

Comment: Si está fuera de los índices, haz que el método retorne `null`, de lo contrario, devuelve un objeto de tipo `T`.

Comment: @MrDave1999 aunque eso sirve, no es una buena solución, puesto que no informas del error, y tambien podrias tener elementos a null o vacios y no saber si es que,existia un objeto vacio en esa posición o si se producio un error por que la lista no estan grande. Pongo este comentario sobretodo para que el autor y quien no lo sepa sea consciente.

Comment: @Alexmaister La solución es buena y claro que se puede informar el error. En pocas palabras, todo lo puedes codificar en el mismo método. Solo hay que saberlo hacer. Un ejemplo básico [aquí](https://pastebin.com/gWJiNfET). Esa es la forma clásica de hacerlo, la típica que se hace en C puro. Obviamente, preferible sería usar las excepciones que da Java, para aprovechar lo que da el lenguaje, pero aún así, la solución que propuse anteriormente, desde mi perspectiva, no es mala.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Realmente no, en C se utiliza numeros enteros distinto de 0 para informar un error, no null. Por favor no confundas un error con no haber encontrado el dato. Son cosas distintas y se informan de distinta forma.

Comment: @Alexmaister No es del todo cierto. En C, tenemos a la función `malloc` en la cual retorna `NULL` si hubo algún error en la asignación de memoria, así que dependerá de la forma como diseñes la función. Aquí está la definición de lo que es un [error](https://www.wordreference.com/definicion/error). Por lo tanto, si no encuentras el objeto en la lista, no llegaste al resultado esperado (que era encontrarlo), por ende, es un error! Decir que una solución es mala, solo porque no detecta otros errores, eso no es correcto, debido a que, se lo puede comprobar de otras maneras.

Comment: @Alexmaister Un gran ejemplo es el método [find](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.8) de C#, retorna `null` (si T es de tipo de referencia) si el objeto no se encontró en la lista, de lo contrario, devuelve la referencia del objeto encontrado. Simplemente es otro tipo de solución y es correcta. Hasta en C se puede hacer lo mismo: [findAL](https://github.com/MrDave1999/LibraryList/blob/master/src/ArrayList.c#L113).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105265/discussion-between-mrdave1999-and-alexmaister).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esos casos la mejor opción es utilizar Excepciones.

**Excepción**: Es un tipo de objeto que se devuelve desde un método para indicar que ocurrió algún error.

Esto se hace mediante la sentencia "**throw**", es necesario indicar en la cabecera del método el tipo de Excepción que podría llegar a producirse o una mas genérica, con la sentencia "**throws**" (Exception siempre es una posibilidad, ¡NO SE RECOMIENDA!).

Las excepciones que pueda llegar a lanar un método, deben ser capturadas, al realizar una llamada a este. Se realiza con la sentencia "**try-catch-finally**" (El cuerpo de finally puede ser omitido).

**En tu caso**:

Conociendo el tamaño de la lista, cuando se indique un indice que no este comprendido en ese rango, lo correcto es lanzar una Excepción.

El código podría ser el siguiente:

```
public T obtener(int i) throws Exception
{
    if(i < 0 || i >= this.primerNodo.size())
    {
        throw Exception("Indice fuera de rango", 1); //Mensaje y numero id del error
    }
}
```

**La llamada a ese metodo** :

```
try
{
  obj = nodo.obtener(3);
}catch (Exception e)
{
   System.out.println("Error:" + e.getError() + e.getMessage());
   //Mas acciones que se requieran
}finally
{
   //Acciones necesarias antes de abandonar el metodo al producirse el error,  en tu caso ninguna
}
```

En este ejemplo estoy utilizando la clase Exception, la cual es la mas generica y de las que heredan y deben heredar todas las demás Excepciones, pero lo recomendable es crear tus propios tipos. Tambien añado la llamada al metodo "this.primerNodo.size()", suponiendo que puedas tener ese metodo implementado, al igual podrias usar la variable donde guardes el tamaño o la propiedad "length" si usas un array como base.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Voy a integrarlo de inmediato en mi código.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta con mas información.

Comment: He añadido parte de lo que me recomendaste y ya soy capaz de agregar esos errores personalizados, por llamarlos así, me parece genial poder hacer eso. De nuevo, ¡muchas gracias!